# Add a class to the first half of items in a list

Tags: jquery

If I have ten items in a list, how can I dynamically add a class (with jQuery) to the first half of them?

Input:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Desired output:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first-half">1</li>
    <li class="first-half">2</li>
    <li class="first-half">3</li>
    <li class="first-half">4</li>
    <li class="first-half">5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You've been here for a year and a half, so I think it's high time you read the formatting FAQ. We don't use `<pre>` and over-the-top HTML entity encoding here; we use Markdown.

Comment: This: http://bit.ly/nVBBE9 ? Or is there something more official? A link would be helpful. I don't remember seeing anything in the general FAQ. Perhaps that should be added so even people who are here less than a year would be more easily able to find it :)

Comment: The highlighted question mark symbol next to the formatting bar that appears when you write your question. It's right there, maybe 3 pixels away from the place where you spent several minutes typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general solution would be:

```
var $lis = $("ul li");
$lis.slice(0, Math.floor($lis.length/2)).addClass("first-half");
```

If you're sure you will always have an even number, you can omit `Math.floor`, and remember, there is also `Math.ceil` if you would prefer to round up.

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/JyPgd/)